# Time tracking web-app that calculates overtime hours

Tags: web-apps, time-management

Currently I use toggl to track my time, but I am missing one feature: Let's say I have a client that I work for X hours a week, fixed, every week, minus holidays. I would like to have a tool (preferable free) that automatically compares worked hours with the target value and shows an accumulated sum of overtime or hours in debt.

It does not have to be an app, a website that I can access from multiple PCs would be just fine.

Comment: Maybe FreshBooks.  I vaguely remember it having this feature.

Comment: @aparente001 Thanks, but the smallest plan in $ 13.50 / month (5 clients). I only need one client and only time tracking. I would prefer a free service. I updates my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you can manage your own website (this software need to be installed on a server), you could try project Kimai (http://www.kimai.org/). As an open source and free project, you can hire someone to put this specific feature, and anything else you want, to the software as needed - this is the very nature of open source software. It will then cost you only what the site costs (there are even free site hosting where you can install your own software).

But even if you can manage a server, the feature you are asking for is  really a simple report... Did you try to ask  it for the company support team? Maybe if this feature is important to you, it could be as well to others, and the company will be glad to hear your suggestion anyway. This is a big plus on paid services, after all...

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I asked the support team of toggl and the one of tracker.toptal.com, but to me the responses did not look like the feature will be available in the near future.